# T test with one group

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, t-test, ggplot2

I think it is a simple question, but I got many different results and now I am not sure which test to use.
I have one group and 2 different scores (higher scores means higher either positive or negative associations). I want to know whether I have differences between these variables. I need to consider that these scores have a similar behavior, so I expect differences (one score could be higher than the other).
I tried with t-test, but they are used when I have more than 1 group, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's [more than one kind of t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test).

If you have two scores on each person (/observational unit), this would be a [paired samples t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Paired_samples). If you subtract the first of each pair of scores from the second, a [one-sample t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#One-sample_t-test) is performed on the differences.

The test statistic is:

$$t = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu_0}{s/\sqrt{n}} $$

where $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean, $\mu_0$ is the hypothesized mean ($0$ in this case), $s$ is the sample standard deviation, and $n$ the sample size (number of differences).

This test statistic is then compared with a $t$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

If you reject the null that the mean of the differences is zero, this is the same as rejecting a null that the two sets of values have the same mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you are taking 2 measurements on each subject and want to find if they have similar behavior, then Bland-Altman techniques are probably a better approach than a t-test.  [Here](http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~mb55/meas/meas.htm) is one website with more details (maintained by Martin Bland).